# How can I get values values from a table and also not in that table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables: Player(name, email) and TeamPlayer(PlayerName, Team, Active). Tables Player and TeamPlayer are connected via Player.name = TeamPlayer.PlayerName.

I want to get all the elements of TeamPlayer, but also the elements in Player not in TeamPlayer. The attribute Active is important also. I execute the next command, but it did not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Player.Name, TeamPlayer.Team, TeamPlayer.Active FROM Player LEFT JOIN TeamPlayer ON TeamPlayer.PlayerName=Player.Name ORDER BY TeamPlayer.Active;
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` for the table `TeamPlayer` and the rows from `Player` that don't exist in `TeamPlayer`:

```
SELECT PlayerName AS Name, Team, null AS email, Active 
FROM TeamPlayer 
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Name, null, t.email, 0 
FROM Player t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TeamPlayer
  WHERE PlayerName = t.Name 
)
ORDER BY Active
```

Since the 2 tables don't have the same columns, the non existing columns for each case will be `NULL` or `0` for the column `Active`.
You can change it as you wish.